# For loop to change dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, spyder

I have a dataframe with multiple columns that have null values. I used the following code to get the specific columns as well as their datatypes. My dataframe is called data here.

```
missing = data.columns[data.isnull().any()].tolist()

data_type_dict = {}
for i in missing:
    print({i:data[i].isnull().sum()})
    data_type_dict.update({i:data[i].dtypes})
print(data_type_dict)
```

Now I want to get replace the null values with medians for my numeric columns, and with mode for type object. I was hoping to split this into first based on data type, so float is separate and object is separate. This is what I did for that. I'm only posting one, which is shorter, there were two dfs that I made.

```
lisnum = data[['MasVnrArea','GarageYrBlt']]
```

Now, firstly, the other one is much longer, so its not just a question of two columns. For this, I want to get each column's median and replace the null values with the median. I was hoping to do this in a for loop.
Essentially I want to do something like this:

```
data['MasVnrArea'].fillna(median, inplace = True)
```

but with a for loop for each column that lisnum has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a for loop

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2, np.nan, 4,5,6],
                'y': [1,2,4,5,6, np.nan],
                'z': [np.nan, 1,0,1,0,1]})
df.fillna(df.median(), inplace=True)
```

this works, for all columns at once.

Comment: Hi PalimPalim, thanks, that worked. I just have a followup question, if you know. In your example, it was just df. In mine, I have data as my original dataset, and lisobj as a dataset containing all the columns with null values. I want the permanent changes to data. So where you put df, would I use data or lisobj?

Comment: I think you can use it on both, but I would do `data.fillna(data.median(), inplace=True)` the code should also work for columns which do not have any na values